# Brew Doctor Warnings in Multi-User Configuration

Tags: rvm, homebrew

I am installing RVM on both user accounts on my computer, for which I need to install Homebrew. I have successfully installed Homebrew, run `brew doctor`, and then installed RVM on the first account without a hitch. Switching to the second, Homebrew is installed but installing RVM meets this message `ERROR: '/usr/local/Cellar' is not writable - it is required for Homebrew, try 'brew doctor' to fix it!`.

Running `brew doctor` on this second account brings up several warnings:

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: /usr/local/etc isn't writable.

This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by
by Homebrew. If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.

You should probably `chown` /usr/local/etc

Warning: /usr/local/include isn't writable.

This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by
by Homebrew. If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.

You should probably `chown` /usr/local/include

Warning: /usr/local/lib isn't writable.

This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by
by Homebrew. If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.

You should probably `chown` /usr/local/lib

Warning: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig isn't writable.

This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by
by Homebrew. If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.

You should probably `chown` /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig

Warning: /usr/local/share isn't writable.

This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by
by Homebrew. If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.

You should probably `chown` /usr/local/share

Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/man aren't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to add locale information to one of these
directories, then the install will fail during the link step.
You should probably `chown` them:

    /usr/local/share/man
    /usr/local/share/man/man1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homebrew isn't designed for multi user account use. What is does is take control of usr/local changing its ownership to the user who installed it. So it works fine for your first user (who installed homebrew) but fails for the second user.

You can find alternative install instructions to get around this [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Installation.md#4)

Another approach you could take is to share the ownership of usr/local between both accounts, making both users members of the same group, and giving group ownership to usr/local might work. However this could have some strange side effects.